# How to get the response of my Java Request Sampler in JMeter to reflect on all the available listeners

Tags: performance, jmeter

I am using Java Request to send a byte of stream array to my web service endpoint.

And i found there is no response from the sampler since it is a customized one.

I can't use any of the listeners since there is no response.

Could someone tell me how can i get my java request sampler response to reflect in the listeners.

This is because listeners is the place where I will be actually observing the performance of the web service

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are storing response from your web service in `String` var called response, you could do this:

```
SampleResult result = new SampleResult();
result.setResponseData(response.getBytes());

/* You may also set other result properties: */
result.setResponseOK();
result.setSuccessful(true);
result.setResponseCodeOK();
result.setDataEncoding(UTF);

/* After you have set all you want, just set result to your sampler */
JMeterContextService.getContext().setPreviousResult(result);
```

I think it should work as needed.

Comment: This is for samplers, not listeners. With this in your sampler, any listener which collects results from samplers with pick it up...

Answer (score 1):

Minimal required JavaRequest class assumes extending from [AbstractJavaSamplerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/AbstractJavaSamplerClient.html) therefore it should have [runTest() method implementation](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerClient.html#runTest-org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSamplerContext-) which returns a [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)

So you can use this `SampleResult` class to control the output of your sampler, minimal working code of a sampler which returns "Hello" string will be something like:

```
package test;

import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.AbstractJavaSamplerClient;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSamplerContext;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;


public class SimpleJavaRequest extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {
    @Override
    public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
        SampleResult result = new SampleResult();
        result.setResponseData("Hello", "UTF-8");
        return result;
    }
}
```

If you compile the above class, drop it into [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and restart JMeter you will see `test.SimpleJavaRequest` class in the "Classname" dropdown

[image: JMeter Java Request]

Upon execution you will get "Hello" as the response data:

[image: JMeter Java Sampler Hello]

More information:

- [How to write a plugin for JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html)
- [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance)